# jQuery colorpicker not working on added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, color-picker

I have these widgets  with a sliding box inside.
There are two widgets when the page is loaded, but you can add a widget and delete it again.

Inside the sliding box is a color picker, and on the starter widgets the color picker works properly, but in the added widgets the color picker doesn't work.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fULQZ/

I think the error is in the script for the color picker?

Here's the script for the color picker:

```
// Color picker
function updateBackground(color) {
    $(this).parents(".box_header").css("background", color.toHexString());
}


$(function() {


$(".flatPalette").spectrum({
    flat: true,
    showInput: true,
    showPaletteOnly: true,
    showPalette:true,
    maxPaletteSize: 10,
    palette: [
         ['#DDD','#9fd0d3', '#c9a9d1', '#e2a6a5', '#c2d2bd','#9fb2d1', '#dbba97', '#cbefe9', '#e6e8bf'],
        []
    ],
    change: updateBackground
});


});
```

Comment: does jQuery is loaded in your page.??? is it newer version of it..??? does is included before other dependent js.?

Comment: @DipeshParmar I'm not quite sure what you mean?

But yes as you can see jQuery is loaded, and the color picker works on the two widgets that's there from the start.

I don't understand the last question?

Comment: does it working on your side.??

Comment: yes partly... as mentioned above.

Check the http://jsfiddle.net/fULQZ/

But the color picker doesn't work on the newly added widgets

Comment: try http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery that will help..

Comment: okay, thank you. But I can't quite see how include the selector in the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extract your spectrum init in a dedicated function, change it a bit the selector to get all non init ones, and just call this function after the gridster.add_widget

```
function addSpectrum(){
    $(".flatPalette:empty").spectrum({ ... }); // :empty will get non init box
};

$('.addbox').on("click", function(){
    gridster.add_widget(' ... ', 2, 1);
    addSpectrum(); // add spectrum on the new box
});

addSpectrum(); // init spectrum on non dynamic box
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fULQZ/1/

Comment: Thank this is great, so now it's up to date

Comment: This approach is fine for smaller applications, but quickly gets messy with bigger ones. You have to always remember to initialize a component when you place it on the screen. Is there a better way? Some sort of automatic initialization if a class is detected?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268661/jquery-on-create-event-for-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 0):

you need a "live" selector to match element added on runtime, check http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: How and where would you go about, adding the "live" selector?

on the `$(".flatPalette").spectrum({` or `function updateBackground(color) {`

Comment: well, as far as I know there is no 'elementCreated' event so you can either add the call to function to the same function where the widgets are created, or try the 'deprecated' live like this $(".flatPalette").live('mouseenter',function(){ $(this).spectrum();};)

Comment: .live is deprecated and here it will call spectrum init at each click, you have luck than the plugin check is init before do his job