# jQuery "on create" event for dynamically-created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I need to be able to dynamically create `<select>` element and turn it into jQuery `.combobox()`. This should be element creation event, as opposed to some "click" event in which case I could just use jQuery `.on()`.

So does something like this exist?

```
$(document).on("create", "select", function() {
    $(this).combobox();
}
```

I'm reluctant to use livequery, because it's very outdated.

**UPDATE** The mentioned select/combobox is loaded via ajax into a jQuery colorbox (modal window), thus the problem - I can only initiate combobox using colorbox `onComplete`, however on change of one combobox another select/combobox must be dynamically created, therefor I need a more generic way to detect creation of an element (`select`in this case).

**UPDATE2** To try and explain the problem further - I have `select/combobox` elements created recursively, there is also a lot of initiating code inside `.combobox()`, therefore if I used a classic approach, like in [@bipen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15268861/82548), my code would inflate to insane levels. Hope this explains the problem better.

**UPDATE3** Thanks everyone, I now understand that since deprecation of `DOMNodeInserted` there is a void left in DOM mutation and there is no solution to this problem. I'll just have to rethink my application.

Comment: May be with the ready event?
`$(select).ready(function() { });`

Comment: @PabloBanderas `ready` is used to: "Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded." (from jquery.com)

Comment: Why not apply the `combobox()` method at the point of creation/insertion, rather than afterwards?

Comment: @DavidThomas Tried to explain the reason in my second update

Comment: So `$(document).on('onComplete', 'select', function(){ // bind here? });`? (Obviously use a closer parent than the `document`, though.)

Comment: @DavidThomas onComplete is colorbox specific event, however I need to detect elements created after colorbox is loaded.

Comment: It is, yes: but if the event is triggered (and allowed to bubble/propagate) it can still be caught by the `on()` method and event-delegation.

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support?

Comment: @DavidThomas colorbox is just a complication of a problem, but what I'm looking for is more generic solution which would work despite of colorbox being present or not.

Answer (score 63):

You can [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) the `DOMNodeInserted` event to get an event for when it's added to the document by your code.

```
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', 'select', function () {
      //$(this).combobox();
});

$('<select>').appendTo('body');
$('<select>').appendTo('body');
```

Fiddled here: http://jsfiddle.net/Codesleuth/qLAB2/3/

EDIT: after reading around I just need to double check `DOMNodeInserted` won't cause problems across browsers. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143929/domnodeinserted-equivalent-in-ie) from 2010 suggests IE doesn't support the event, so test it if you can.

See here: [[link]](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeInserted) *Warning! the DOMNodeInserted event type is defined in this specification for reference and completeness, but this specification [deprecates](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#glossary-deprecated) the use of this event type.*

Comment: isn't `.delegate` deprecated from jQuery version 1.7 and superseeded by `.on`?

Comment: Yea, you're right. I'll modify this answer, but I'm honestly unsure if you should use this since `DOMNodeInserted` is deprecated now.

Comment: I've tried `on('DOMNodeInserted'` before I posted this question. It obviously didn't work.

Comment: Since it isn't in your question that you have tried it, I would say that's an unfair vote. In any case, I can't help you here.

Answer (score 29):

As mentioned in several other answers, [mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) have been deprecated, so you should use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead. Since nobody has given any details on that yet, here it goes...

### Basic JavaScript API

The API for MutationObserver is fairly simple. It's not quite as simple as the mutation events, but it's still okay.

```js
function callback(records) {
  records.forEach(function (record) {
    var list = record.addedNodes;
    var i = list.length - 1;
    
 for ( ; i > -1; i-- ) {
   if (list[i].nodeName === 'SELECT') {
     // Insert code here...
     console.log(list[i]);
   }
 }
  });
}

var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

var targetNode = document.body;

observer.observe(targetNode, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

```html
<script>
  // For testing
  setTimeout(function() {
    var $el = document.createElement('select');
    document.body.appendChild($el);
  }, 500);
</script>
```

Let's break that down.

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
```

This creates the observer. The observer isn't watching anything yet; this is just where the event listener gets attached.

```
observer.observe(targetNode, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

This makes the observer start up. The first argument is the node that the observer will watch for changes on. The second argument is the [options for what to watch for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserverInit).

- `childList` means I want to watch for child elements being added or removed.
- `subtree` is a modifier that *extends* `childList` to watch for changes anywhere in this element's subtree (otherwise, it would just look at changes directly within `targetNode`).

The other two main options besides `childList` are `attributes` and `characterData`, which mean about what they sound like. You must use one of those three.

```
function callback(records) {
  records.forEach(function (record) {
```

Things get a little tricky inside the callback. The callback receives an array of [MutationRecord](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord)s. Each MutationRecord can describe several changes of one type (`childList`, `attributes`, or `characterData`). Since I only told the observer to watch for `childList`, I won't bother checking the type.

```
var list = record.addedNodes;
```

Right here I grab a NodeList of all the child nodes that were added. This will be empty for all the records where nodes aren't added (and there may be many such records).

From there on, I loop through the added nodes and find any that are `<select>` elements.

Nothing really complex here.

### jQuery

...but you asked for jQuery. Fine.

```js
(function($) {

  var observers = [];

  $.event.special.domNodeInserted = {

    setup: function setup(data, namespaces) {
      var observer = new MutationObserver(checkObservers);

      observers.push([this, observer, []]);
    },

    teardown: function teardown(namespaces) {
      var obs = getObserverData(this);

      obs[1].disconnect();

      observers = $.grep(observers, function(item) {
        return item !== obs;
      });
    },

    remove: function remove(handleObj) {
      var obs = getObserverData(this);

      obs[2] = obs[2].filter(function(event) {
        return event[0] !== handleObj.selector && event[1] !== handleObj.handler;
      });
    },

    add: function add(handleObj) {
      var obs = getObserverData(this);

      var opts = $.extend({}, {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
      }, handleObj.data);

      obs[1].observe(this, opts);

      obs[2].push([handleObj.selector, handleObj.handler]);
    }
  };

  function getObserverData(element) {
    var $el = $(element);

    return $.grep(observers, function(item) {
      return $el.is(item[0]);
    })[0];
  }

  function checkObservers(records, observer) {
    var obs = $.grep(observers, function(item) {
      return item[1] === observer;
    })[0];

    var triggers = obs[2];

    var changes = [];

    records.forEach(function(record) {
      if (record.type === 'attributes') {
        if (changes.indexOf(record.target) === -1) {
          changes.push(record.target);
        }

        return;
      }

      $(record.addedNodes).toArray().forEach(function(el) {
        if (changes.indexOf(el) === -1) {
          changes.push(el);
        }
      })
    });

    triggers.forEach(function checkTrigger(item) {
      changes.forEach(function(el) {
        var $el = $(el);

        if ($el.is(item[0])) {
          $el.trigger('domNodeInserted');
        }
      });
    });
  }

})(jQuery);
```

This creates a new event called `domNodeInserted`, using the [jQuery special events API](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/jquery-special-events/). You can use it like so:

```
$(document).on("domNodeInserted", "select", function () {
  $(this).combobox();
});
```

*I would personally suggest looking for a class because some libraries will create `select` elements for testing purposes.*

Naturally, you can also use `.off("domNodeInserted", ...)` or fine-tune the watching by passing in data like this:

```
$(document.body).on("domNodeInserted", "select.test", {
  attributes: true,
  subtree: false
}, function () {
  $(this).combobox();
});
```

This would trigger checking for the appearance of a `select.test` element whenever attributes changed for elements directly inside the body.

You can see it live below or on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sb2n60dq/).

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).on("domNodeInserted", "select", function() {
    console.log(this);
    //$(this).combobox();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  // For testing
  setTimeout(function() {
    var $el = document.createElement('select');
    document.body.appendChild($el);
  }, 500);
</script>

<script>
  (function($) {

    var observers = [];

    $.event.special.domNodeInserted = {

      setup: function setup(data, namespaces) {
        var observer = new MutationObserver(checkObservers);

        observers.push([this, observer, []]);
      },

      teardown: function teardown(namespaces) {
        var obs = getObserverData(this);

        obs[1].disconnect();

        observers = $.grep(observers, function(item) {
          return item !== obs;
        });
      },

      remove: function remove(handleObj) {
        var obs = getObserverData(this);

        obs[2] = obs[2].filter(function(event) {
          return event[0] !== handleObj.selector && event[1] !== handleObj.handler;
        });
      },

      add: function add(handleObj) {
        var obs = getObserverData(this);

        var opts = $.extend({}, {
          childList: true,
          subtree: true
        }, handleObj.data);

        obs[1].observe(this, opts);

        obs[2].push([handleObj.selector, handleObj.handler]);
      }
    };

    function getObserverData(element) {
      var $el = $(element);

      return $.grep(observers, function(item) {
        return $el.is(item[0]);
      })[0];
    }

    function checkObservers(records, observer) {
      var obs = $.grep(observers, function(item) {
        return item[1] === observer;
      })[0];

      var triggers = obs[2];

      var changes = [];

      records.forEach(function(record) {
        if (record.type === 'attributes') {
          if (changes.indexOf(record.target) === -1) {
            changes.push(record.target);
          }

          return;
        }

        $(record.addedNodes).toArray().forEach(function(el) {
          if (changes.indexOf(el) === -1) {
            changes.push(el);
          }
        })
      });

      triggers.forEach(function checkTrigger(item) {
        changes.forEach(function(el) {
          var $el = $(el);

          if ($el.is(item[0])) {
            $el.trigger('domNodeInserted');
          }
        });
      });
    }

  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

---

#### Note

This jQuery code is a fairly basic implementation. It does not trigger in cases where modifications elsewhere make your selector valid.

For example, suppose your selector is `.test select` and the document already has a `<select>`. Adding the class `test` to `<body>` will make the selector valid, but because I only check `record.target` and `record.addedNodes`, the event would not fire. The change has to happen to the element you wish to select itself.

This could be avoided by querying for the selector whenever mutations happen. I chose not to do that to avoid causing duplicate events for elements that had already been handled. Properly dealing with [adjacent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) or [general sibling combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) would make things even trickier.

For a more comprehensive solution, see https://github.com/pie6k/jquery.initialize, as mentioned in [Damien Ó Ceallaigh](/users/1350377/damien-%c3%93-ceallaigh)'s [answer](/a/39339340/5764553). However, the author of that library has announced that the library is old and suggests that you shouldn't use jQuery for this.

Comment: Amazing.  Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

<s>You can use `DOMNodeInserted` mutation event (no need delegation):</s>

```
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    var target = e.target; //inserted element;
});
```

EDIT: [Mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) are **deprecated**, use [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead

Answer (score 10):

Just came up with this solution that seems to solve all my ajax problems.

For on ready events I now use this:

```
function loaded(selector, callback){
    //trigger after page load.
    $(function () {
        callback($(selector));
    });
    //trigger after page update eg ajax event or jquery insert.
    $(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', selector, function () {
        callback($(this));
    });
}

loaded('.foo', function(el){
    //some action
    el.css('background', 'black');
});
```

And for normal trigger events I now use this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.foo', function () {
    //some action
    $(this).css('background', 'pink');
});
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a plugin, [`pie6k/jquery.initialize`](https://github.com/pie6k/jquery.initialize), which is based on `MutationObserver` that achieves this simply:

```
$.initialize('select', function() {
    $(this).combobox();
});
```

Update 2024: there is also a non-jQuery equivalent, [`bezborodow/mutation-initialiser`](https://github.com/bezborodow/mutation-initialiser):

```
initialise('select', select => {
    select.combobox();
});
```

Comment: See also [`bezborodow/mutation-initialiser`](https://github.com/bezborodow/mutation-initialiser) for a non-jQuery alternative.

Answer (score 4):

This could be done with [`DOM4 MutationObservers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver) but will only work in Firefox 14+/Chrome 18+ (for now).

However there is an "[epic hack](http://www.backalleycoder.com/2012/04/25/i-want-a-damnodeinserted/)" (author's words not mine!) that works in all browsers that support CSS3 animations which are: IE10, Firefox 5+, Chrome 3+, Opera 12, Android 2.0+, Safari 4+. See the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zzw2M/33/light/) from the blog. The hack is to use a CSS3 animation event with a given name that is observed and acted upon in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

One way, which *seems* reliable (though tested only in Firefox and Chrome) is to use JavaScript to listen for the `animationend` (or its camelCased, and prefixed, sibling `animationEnd`) event, and apply a short-lived (in the demo 0.01 second) animation to the element-type you plan to add. This, of course, is not an `onCreate` event, but approximates (in *compliant* browsers) an `onInsertion` type of event; the following is a proof-of-concept:

```
$(document).on('webkitAnimationEnd animationend MSAnimationEnd oanimationend', function(e){
    var eTarget = e.target;
    console.log(eTarget.tagName.toLowerCase() + ' added to ' + eTarget.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase());
    $(eTarget).draggable(); // or whatever other method you'd prefer
});
```

With the following HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <button class="add">add a div element</button>
</div>
```

And (abbreviated, prefixed-versions-removed though present in the Fiddle, below) CSS:

```
/* vendor-prefixed alternatives removed for brevity */
@keyframes added {
    0% {
        color: #fff;
    }
}

div {
    color: #000;
    /* vendor-prefixed properties removed for brevity */
    animation: added 0.01s linear;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/v2TRR/2/).

Obviously the CSS can be adjusted to suit the placement of the relevant elements, as well as the selector used in the jQuery (it should really be as close to the point of insertion as possible).

Documentation of the event-names:

```
Mozilla   |  animationend
Microsoft |  MSAnimationEnd
Opera     |  oanimationend
Webkit    |  webkitAnimationEnd
W3C       |  animationend
```

References:

- [caniuse.com summary of compatibility of CSS Animations](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation).
- [CSS AnimationEvent Interface (W3C)](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-animations/#AnimationEvent-interface).
- [JavaScript `animationend` vendor-support](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/).

Answer (score 4):

For me binding to the body does not work. Binding to the document using jQuery.bind() does.

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted',function(e){
             var target = e.target;
         });
```

Comment: [Mutation Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationEvent) like [`DOMNodeInserted`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeInserted) are deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

instead of...

```
$(".class").click( function() {
    // do something
});
```

You can write...

```
$('body').on('click', '.class', function() {
    // do something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I Think it's worth mentioning that in some cases, this would work:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
// Do Stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

create a `<select>` with id , append it to document.. and call `.combobox`

```
  var dynamicScript='<select id="selectid"><option value="1">...</option>.....</select>'
  $('body').append(dynamicScript); //append this to the place your wanted.
  $('#selectid').combobox();  //get the id and add .combobox();
```

this should do the trick.. you can hide the select if you want and after `.combobox` show it..or else use find..

```
 $(document).find('select').combobox() //though this is not good performancewise
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are using angularjs you can write your own directive. I had the same problem whith bootstrapSwitch. I have to call
    `$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();`
in javascript but my html input object was not created at that time. So I write an own directive and create the input element with
    `<input type="checkbox" checkbox-switch>`

In the directive I compile the element to get access via javascript an execute the jquery command (like your `.combobox()` command). Very important is to remove the attribute. Otherwise this directive will call itself and you have build a loop

```
app.directive("checkboxSwitch", function($compile) {
return {
    link: function($scope, element) {
        var input = element[0];
        input.removeAttribute("checkbox-switch");
        var inputCompiled = $compile(input)($scope.$parent);
        inputCompiled.bootstrapSwitch();
    }
}
});
```

Comment: The question related to jQuery alone, not AngularJS. The solution should be confined to jQuery and jQuery plugins.