# Apply image centering and cropping after dynamically loading an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I want to center and crop images even for images that are dynamically loaded later.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="iThumbnail">
        <img src="images/art-vertical.jpeg" alt=""/>
    </div>
</body>
```

The `body` content above is static the first time.
Later, `body` contents are loaded/replaced dynamically with other image sources.

So, for the static content, I'm able to center and crop the images with the below code (thanks to [jonathanNicol](http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2014/06/16/centre-crop-thumbnails-with-css/) and [nickCraver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3877079/2619658)).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function thumbnailImageCropCenter() {
        $('.iThumbnail').find('img').one('load', function() {
            if (($(this).height() > $(this).width()) && ($(this).height() != 0) ) {
                $(this).addClass('portraitView');
            }
        }).each(function() {
            if(this.complete) $(this).load();
        });
    }
    thumbnailImageCropCenter();
});
```

I want to avoid calling `thumbnailImageCropCenter()` every time I load a page content dynamically.

Question: Is there a way to automatically bind `thumbnailImageCropCenter()` to `body` such that it applies to all the images within `body`, no matter if images were loaded dynamically later.

PS: replacing `.one()` with `.bind()` didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').on('load', '.iThumbnail img', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if (($this.height() > $this.width()) && ($this.height() != 0) ) {
       $this.addClass('portraitView');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I get the concept. But `$('body').on('load', ....)` is not getting triggered, even if I put a `console.log` in it. Any suggestions please ?

Comment: I guess `$('body').on('load', ....)` isn't expected to work .. from http://api.jquery.com/on/ ... In all browsers, the load, scroll, and error events (e.g., on an <img> element) do not bubble. In Internet Explorer 8 and lower, the paste and reset events do not bubble. Such events are not supported for use with delegation, but they can be used when the event handler is directly attached to the element generating the event.

Comment: Yep, I have checked, it does not work( Some "bubble" issues with "load".. So I think your code is best option then.

Comment: You can try to track new HTML elements on the page - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268661/jquery-on-create-event-for-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Thanks again for checking ... there seem to be some deprecation problem. Pity, there doesn't seem to be an elegant solution.