# javascript event for each time element exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

An external script that I use, generates divs of a certain class from time to time, it can happen unlimited amount of times. I'm trying to run a function **each time** such element is being created. I tried using `$('selector').live(function(){})` and `$('selector').waitUntilExists(function(){})` but it's only valid for the first time it's created. how can I create some kind of a listener that will call a function each time a new element of this class is being created?

Thanks

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268661/jquery-on-create-event-for-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As you want to create elements dynamically.**

You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

*General Syntax*

```
$(document).on(event, selector, eventHandler);
```

Ideally you should replace `document` with closest static container.