# Add a jQuery function to an existing one with a separate file

Tags: jquery, wordpress

So here is my problem:

I'm using a Wordpress plugin that handles my forms (contact form 7). Within that plugin there is a function that shows a message, when a mail is been successfully sent(not succesfully submitted). But the message stays there until the page is reloaded. I want to remove that message after a few seconds. The message is in a div with a class of `.wpcf7-repsonse-output`.

Contactform 7 provides, within the admin section of the plugin, an option to add custom code after an event, so I added this:

```
jQuery('.wpcf7-response-output').delay(3000).slideUp(400);
```

The code does what it suppose to do, but does it right after the event and after that the standard function fires, so the message is still there...

I have found the function that handles this event and I can add my code to it to work, but when the plugin gets an update, my code is obviously gone.

I would prefer not to add my code to the admin section of the plugin aswell. So I would like to create a separate file where my code hooks into the existing functionality. Is that possible?

Thank you.

Comment: You can listen to the event where the div is created, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15268923/416947

Comment: @Ohad, thnx for your reply, but PHP creates the div and decides which one to show. jQuery just handles the visibility.