# on DOMNodeInserted not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268661/jquery-on-create-event-for-dynamically-created-elements), I wrote the following code:

```
$(function() {
    $( document ).on('DOMNodeInserted',"span:contains('Suggested Post')", function() {
        console.log("New Suggested Post found");
    })
})
```

As I scroll down the page and these elements are created, I do not see the console message I expect to see.  However, if I manually input `$("span:contains('Suggested Post')").length` in the console, the output continues to increase.

Ideas?

Snippet requested by @Barmar.  It doesn't behave exactly like my real-world scenario, but it's still not right...

```js
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', "div:contains('Banana')", function() {
  console.log("new banana detected!");
});

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  var fruit = '';
  switch (Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1)) {
    case 1:
      fruit = 'Apple'
      break;
    case 2:
      fruit = 'Orange'
      break;
    case 3:
      fruit = 'Banana'
      break;
    default:
      fruit = "WTF"
  }
  $('#fakeDocument').append('<div>' + fruit + '</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fakeDocument">
  <strong>Banana Detector</strong>
  <button id="btn" type="button">Add Banana!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: With your delegation, your handler is only triggered if the elements are created **inside** an element that matches the selector, not if the element that's created matches the selector.

Comment: ahhhhh, I see.  Any suggestions for modification?

Comment: Hmm, I could be wrong about that. https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeInserted says that `event.target` is the node being inserted, not the container. And jQuery matches the selector against the target.

Comment: Can you create a Stack Snippet that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Ummm, I kind of did.  I'll work on it some more.

Comment: For some reason it fires every time but it fires twice when there is an actual match.  Not sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind the delegation to the immediate parent of the elements that are being inserted.

The reason for this is that the `DOMNodeInserted` event bubbles up. If you bind it to an outer container, it will bubble up to a containing DIV, and that DIV will match `:contains(Banana)` because of the `Banana Detector` heading. And even if you move that out of the container, it will match because of previously added nodes that contain `Banana`.

This is why you got two firings when there was an actual match: it would fire once for the new element that matches, and again for the container that always matches.

I initially thought that `event.StopPropagation()` would solve the problem, but it doesn't. It will prevent double firings when there's an actual match. But it will still fire when there's no match -- the event doesn't fire on the new element (because it doesn't match), so `event.stopPropagation()` doesn't run, so it bubbles out to the container that matches.

```js
$("#fakeDocument").on('DOMNodeInserted', "div:contains('Banana')", function() {
  console.log("new banana detected!");
});

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  var fruit = '';
  switch (Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1)) {
    case 1:
      fruit = 'Apple'
      break;
    case 2:
      fruit = 'Orange'
      break;
    case 3:
      fruit = 'Banana'
      break;
    default:
      fruit = "WTF"
  }
  $('#fakeDocument').append('<div>' + fruit + '</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fakeDocument">
  <strong>Banana Detector</strong>
  <button id="btn" type="button">Add Banana!</button>
</div>
```